# Show that concatenating the bases of the eigenspaces of distinct eigenvalues is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation, prove that if $T$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m$, and a concatenation of the bases of the eigenspaces $E_1,\ldots,E_m$ is a basis $B$ for $V$, that the $B$-matrix of $T$ is diagonal.

I'm just looking for the most simple explanation of why this is true. If the basis for $V$ is just one matrix, then how can the coordinate vector for the $B$-matrix be diagonal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to avoid excessive formality, a rigorous proof of everything I mention here can be found in any linear algebra book (Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra is a great book, in case you need one).

When you say that a concatenation of the basis of the eigenspaces $E_1, ..., E_m$ is a basis for $\mathbb{V}$, you're actually saying that

$$\mathbb{V} = \oplus_{i=1}^mE_i$$

Now, let $f_i$ be the restriction of $f$ to $E_i$. Notice that, given a basis $\beta_i = \{v_{i1}, ..., v_{ik_i}\}$ of $E_i$:

$$f_iv_{ij} = \lambda_i v_{ij}$$

This is essentially because of the definition of f and because the $v_{ij}$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. We know that a linear operator's matrix in $\beta_i$ is

$$[f_i]_{\beta_i} = \begin{pmatrix}
(f_iv_{i1})_{\beta_i} | ... | (f_i v_{ik_i})_{\beta_i}
\end{pmatrix}$$

But notice that

$$(f_iv_{ij})_{\beta_i} = (\lambda_iv_{ij})_{\beta_i} = \lambda_i (v_{ij})_{\beta_i} = \lambda_ie_j$$

Where $e_j$ is the canonical column vector with zeros at every position but the j-th. That means that $f_i$ in $\beta_i$ is a matrix of the form:

$$[f_i]_{\beta_i} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_i\\
&\ddots\\
&&\lambda_i\\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{F}^{k_i \times k_i}$$

Where the blanks are zeros. Now, vectors in $B_i$ are linearly independent from those of $B_j$ whenever $i\neq j$, because they're eigenvectors from distinct eigenvalues. This means, you could take the "ordered union" $\beta = \cup_{i=1}^m \beta_i$; then $\beta = \{v_{11}, ..., v_{1k_1}, ..., v_{m1}, ..., v_{mk_m}\}$ and notice that $[f]_\beta$ is a block matrix of the form

$$[f]_\beta = \begin{pmatrix}
[f_1]_{\beta_1} \\
& \ddots \\
&& [f_m]_{\beta_m}
\end{pmatrix}$$

In which once again, the blanks are zeros. However, the $[f_i]_{\beta_i}$ are diagonal matrices. Hence, $[f]_\beta$ is also a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your other post, so I'm making a leap of faith that V is finite dimensional.  If that's not the case, then ignore this.

Let $B=(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$ be the eigenbasis.  Since $(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$ is a basis for V, the $B$ matrix can be expressed as:
$B=[\{T(v_1)\}_B \{T(v_2)\}_B \cdots\{T(v_n)\}_B]$.
Since $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ are eigenvectors of $T$,
$T(v_i)=\lambda_{v_i} v_i$ ($\lambda_{v_i}$ is the associated eigenvalue with respect to $v_i$).
Also, since $B=(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$,
$\{v_i\}_B=e_i$, where $e_i$ is the vector with $0$'s in every coordinate except the ith coordinate which has a $1$.
Therefore,
$B=[\{T(v_1)\}_B \{T(v_2)\}_B \cdots\{T(v_n)\}_B] = [\{\lambda_{v_1}v_1\}_B \{\lambda_{v_2}v_2\}_B \cdots\{\lambda_{v_n} v_n\}_B]=[\{\lambda_{v_1}e_1\} \{\lambda_{v_2}e_2\} c\dots\{\lambda_{v_n} e_n\}]$
which is a diagonal matrix.

Hope this helps

Comment: $V$ is finite dimensional. I'm just wondering what the fact that the "concatenation of the bases of the eigenspaces is a basis for $V$" means. Where does this come into play in your answer?

Comment: I guess I should have explicitly said this, but the basis $B$ is the concatenation of the bases i.e. if the basis of $E_1$ is $(x_1, x_2,... x_k)$, then $v_1=x_1$, $v_2=x_2$, ... $v_k=x_k$ and if the basis of $E_2$ is $(y_1,... y_i)$ then $v_{k+1}=y_1$.... $v_{k+i}=y_{k+i}$ and so on.

Comment: So "concatenation" just means the basis for $V$ is $(v_1,..,v_n)$ and not $[v_1...v_n]$ (where the latter is a matrix with the bases as the columns)?

Comment: Yes.  A concatenation of the eigenbases (sets of vectors) isn't an matrix.

Comment: OK. Now that makes a lot more sense. I thought concatenation meant concatenating into a matrix, so I was confused that the basis of $V$ had only one element.

Comment: Can you further explain why $T(v_i) = \lambda_i v_i$? That is the only part I don't understand.

Comment: Every $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $T$.